# How should the SAM MD tag match the CIGAR string?

Tags: file-formats, sam, cigar

I am trying to understand how the MD:Z tag is used. The following is from the [SAM Optional Fields Specification](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMtags.pdf), which gives an example but is not thorough.

> The MD field aims to achieve SNP/indel calling without looking at the
>   reference. For example, a string ‘10A5^AC6’ means from the leftmost
>   reference base in the alignment, there are 10 matches followed by an A
>   on the reference which is different from the aligned read base; the
>   next 5 reference bases are matches followed by a 2bp deletion from the
>   reference; the deleted sequence is AC; the last 6 bases are matches.
>   The MD field ought to match the CIGAR string.

Suppose I have a read that I want to soft clip at both ends. If the read starts with CIGAR `100M` and MD `50G49`, and I want to change the CIGAR to `7S86M7S`, what should the MD field become?

Is there a more complete explanation of what appears in the MD tag field?

Answer (score 5):

The MD string doesn't apply to soft or hard clipped regions,. so your example read becomes `43G42`. Since variant calling using something simplistic like this is only ever going to use the aligned portion, I guess there was never much reason to bother with adding in soft-clipping information. This also means that you need to parse the CIGAR string if you're using the MD string.